# Named custom routes in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

I'm trying to write a request spec for a custom action on one of my controllers.

My routes.rb is like this:

```
controller :profile, :path => 'profile' do
  match 'view_friends/:circle_id', :to => :view_friends, :via => [:get], :as => 'view_friends'
end
resources :profile
```

I want to visit this action, and was hoping that as I can use

```
visit profile_path
visit new_profile_path 
etc
```

That I could do

```
visit view_friends_profile_path
```

However this gives me the "error undefined local variable or method "

I can get the desired behavior by writing

```
visit profile_path.to_s + '/view_friends/' + circle.id.to_s
```

But that is horrible. What am I missing to be able to name a custom action?

edit:

Relevant output from rake routes

```
   view_friends GET      (/:locale)/profile/view_friends/:circle_id(.:format)       {:controller=>"profile", :action=>"view_friends"}
```

Comment: Run rake routes to be sure you're using the right helper method. Maybe you could add the output of the command to the question.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'm a bit confused.  Usually in rails when you make a controller, the controller has a plural name.  For instance if your model name is `Profile`, then you would have a `ProfilesController`.  The way you are writing your question implies that your controller is named `ProfileController`.  Seems kind of unusual, so if you could clarify that would be helpful.  That being said, try this:

```
# in routes.rb
resources :profile do
  member do
    match 'view_friends/:circle_id' => :view_friends, :via => :get, :as => 'view_friends'
  end
end
```

Should produce what you want.  You can access it now by doing this:

```
view_friends_profile_path(profile_id, circle_id)
```